# Dynamic website using APACHE HTTP server and CGI script in Python

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I have been reading about APACHE server and CGI scripts. As per my understanding I can create a website if I have an APACHE HTTP server version 2.4 and write CGI scripts using Python. Let say I have a registered domain name with DNS and have a server where APACHE HTTP server 2.4 is installed and configured to run CGI scripts. I also have python installed on it. Can I create a basic dynamic content generating web site by writing CGI scripts in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's possible. CGI is an old webserver interface used to execute programs on the server side. This includes compiled programs and all sorts of scripts.

Nowadays CGI isn't very popular anymore. Mostly because of bad performance and security issues. If you want to execute Python code behind an Apache webserver consider using [mod_wsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).